# Merge 2 monitors on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, 22.04

I have 3 monitors available and I would like to merge 2 of them to be merged so that when maximizing applications, they are fullscreen across those 2 monitors.

I've tried using `xrandr` with `xrandr --setmonitor Joined auto HDMI-0,DP-4` and nothing

I've tried to play with Nvidia settings and their `xinerama` and I feel its so buggy that I lose some brain cells.

I've tried to use `Compiz` but adjusting screen resolution did not change anything.

`xrandr --verbose` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 7680 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (0x1bd) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 800mm x 450mm panning 7680x2160+0+0
    Identifier: 0x1bc
    Timestamp:  19276
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      1 0 2 3
    Panning:    7680x2160+0+0
    Tracking:   7680x2160+0+0
    Border:     0/0/0/0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0061a4e20001000000
        0a1e0103809051780acf74a3574cb023
        09484c210800818081c0614095000101
        01010101010104740030f2705a80b058
        8a0020c23100001e023a801871382d40
        582c450020c23100001e000000fc004d
        692054560a20202020202020000000fd
        00324b1e501e000a20202020202001ab
        02034af251010304050790121314161f
        5d5e5f6263642f097f07150750570600
        3d06c05f7e0183010000e200c96e030c
        003000b83c2f008001020304e50e6061
        6566e305c301e3060501011d00bc52d0
        1e20b8285540c48e2100001e011d80d0
        721c1620102c2580c48e2100009e0000
        000000000000000000000000000000aa
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: HDMI 
    ConnectorNumber: 3 
    _ConnectorLocation: 3 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  3840x2160 (0x1bd) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  30.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x1be) 593.410MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 4184 end 4272 total 4400 skew    0 clock 134.87KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  59.94Hz
  4096x2160 (0x1bf) 594.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 5064 end 5152 total 5280 skew    0 clock 112.50KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  50.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x1c0) 296.700MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 4184 end 4272 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  29.97Hz
  4096x2160 (0x1c1) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 5064 end 5152 total 5280 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  25.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x1c2) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  54.00KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  24.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x1c3) 296.700MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  53.95KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  23.98Hz
  3840x2160 (0x1c4) 593.410MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock 134.87KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  59.94Hz
  3840x2160 (0x1c5) 594.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4896 end 4984 total 5280 skew    0 clock 112.50KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  50.00Hz
  3840x2160 (0x1c6) 296.700MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  29.97Hz
  3840x2160 (0x1c7) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4896 end 4984 total 5280 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  25.00Hz
  3840x2160 (0x1c8) 296.700MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  53.95KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  23.98Hz
  1920x1080 (0x1c9) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x1ca) 148.350MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1920x1080 (0x1cb) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1440x900 (0x1cc) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1280x1024 (0x1cd) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x720 (0x1ce) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x1cf) 74.180MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1280x720 (0x1d0) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x1d1) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x1d2) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  720x576 (0x1d3) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x480 (0x1d4) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x1d5) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x1d6) 25.170MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.46KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.93Hz
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x1d7
    Timestamp:  19276
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      1 0 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
        supported: DisplayPort
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 2 
    _ConnectorLocation: 2 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x1d8
    Timestamp:  19276
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      1 0 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 2 
    _ConnectorLocation: 2 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x1d9
    Timestamp:  19276
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      1 0 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
        supported: DisplayPort
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 1 
    _ConnectorLocation: 1 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x1da
    Timestamp:  19276
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      1 0 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 1 
    _ConnectorLocation: 1 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
DP-4 connected 3840x2160+3840+0 (0x1bd) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 800mm x 450mm
    Identifier: 0x1db
    Timestamp:  19276
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      1 0 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    CTM: 2591090 1 7737 0 2017 -2147483648 41175 -2147483648 -1154733 0 44695 -2147483648 45328 0 21316 -2147483648 
        3727858 1 
    CscMatrix: 65575 0 0 0 0 65518 0 0 0 0 65592 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0061a4e20001000000
        0a1e0103809051780acf74a3574cb023
        09484c210800818081c0614095000101
        01010101010104740030f2705a80b058
        8a0020c23100001e023a801871382d40
        582c450020c23100001e000000fc004d
        692054560a20202020202020000000fd
        00324b1e501e000a20202020202001ab
        02034af251010304050790121314161f
        5d5e5f6263642f097f07150750570600
        3d06c05f7e0183010000e200c96e030c
        003000b83c2f008001020304e50e6061
        6566e305c301e3060501011d00bc52d0
        1e20b8285540c48e2100001e011d80d0
        721c1620102c2580c48e2100009e0000
        000000000000000000000000000000aa
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
        supported: DisplayPort
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 0 
    _ConnectorLocation: 0 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  3840x2160 (0x1bd) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  30.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x1be) 593.410MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 4184 end 4272 total 4400 skew    0 clock 134.87KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  59.94Hz
  4096x2160 (0x1bf) 594.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 5064 end 5152 total 5280 skew    0 clock 112.50KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  50.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x1c0) 296.700MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 4184 end 4272 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  29.97Hz
  4096x2160 (0x1c1) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 5064 end 5152 total 5280 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  25.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x1c2) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  54.00KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  24.00Hz
  4096x2160 (0x1c3) 296.700MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  4096 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  53.95KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  23.98Hz
  3840x2160 (0x1c4) 593.410MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock 134.87KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  59.94Hz
  3840x2160 (0x1c5) 594.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4896 end 4984 total 5280 skew    0 clock 112.50KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  50.00Hz
  3840x2160 (0x1c6) 296.700MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  29.97Hz
  3840x2160 (0x1c7) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4896 end 4984 total 5280 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  25.00Hz
  3840x2160 (0x1c8) 296.700MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  53.95KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  23.98Hz
  1920x1080 (0x1c9) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x1ca) 148.350MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1920x1080 (0x1cb) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1440x900 (0x1cc) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1280x1024 (0x1cd) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x720 (0x1ce) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x1cf) 74.180MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1280x720 (0x1d0) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x1d1) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x1d2) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  720x576 (0x1d3) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x480 (0x1d4) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x1d5) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x1d6) 25.170MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.46KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.93Hz
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x1dc
    Timestamp:  19276
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      1 0 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 0 
    _ConnectorLocation: 0 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to `--setmonitor` and I run into the same issue where listing all monitors to create a virtual monitor does not work. I found that creating the virtual monitor by listing the specs of the monitor and then assigning it to a physical monitor worked for me...like so

`xrandr --setmonitor "monitor_name" "width_px"/"width_mm"x"height_px"/"height_mm"+"x_offset_px"+"y_offset_px" "output_name"`

Comment: How do you "assign it to a physical monitor"?

Comment: Can you post `xrandr --verbose` and I will show you an example. 

Here's something I recently did: [link](https://pastebin.com/inS9yFUc)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out your link. I've also added `xrandr --verbose` output to my original post.